# How does FFT work if the number of points N is not a power of two?

Tags: matlab, fft

In the MATLAB, if I am doing calculation

```
FFT {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

I got results as

```
{ 21, -3+5.196i, -3+1.732i, -3, -3-1.732i, -3-5.196i}
```

Basically `FFT` is working for `2^n` data, then how is it calculated? what is the logic here?

Comment: matlab fft function uses DFT if length is not power of two and it is based on fftw library that can be found at http://www.fftw.org

Comment: There are FFT algorithms that work with lengths that are not power of two. See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Other_FFT_algorithms

Comment: just pad your data with zeros until you have 2^n points

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Answer (score -1):

I got my answer in DSP book, there is composite radix fft, which is working for N number of points.

I have written code for this on python and android.

**My Composite FFT Python Code on GitHub:**

https://github.com/Ashvanee-Patel/Composite_FFT-FFT-DFT-Python

feel free to ask me any question regarding to this.